# Is function in $L^{\infty} (\Omega)$ times function in $H^{1,2} _0 (\Omega)$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

If we have some function $\delta_{i} \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ given by
\begin{equation*}
            \delta_{i} (x,y) = \left\{
            \begin{array}{ll}
             a & \mbox{in } \Omega_1 \\
             b & \mbox{in }  \Omega_2  \\
             c & \mbox{in } \Omega_3 \\
             d& \mbox{in }\Omega_4 \\
            0& else
            \end{array}
        \right.
\end{equation*}
(a,b,c and d just numbers, $\Omega =\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2 \cup \Omega_3 \cup \Omega_4$, all $\Omega_i$ are disjoint) and we have some other function $u \in H^{1,2}_0 (\Omega)$ will the product of these two functions be differentiable? I'm still trying to get the hang of what we learn from the different spaces. Currently the most I understand is that $\delta_{i}$ is essentially bounded and $u$ and $\nabla u$ are both in $L^2 (\Omega)$, meaning that the integral of the square root for each $\nabla u$ and $u$ are bounded. I'm not sure how to use this information to get differentiability.

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No. The product of  $L^\infty$ and $H^1$ functions is in general not weakly differentiable.

Take $\Omega=(-2,2)$, $u\equiv 1$, $v= \chi_{[-1,1]}\in L^\infty$, then $uv=v$ is not in $H^1(\Omega)$. It does not even have weak derivative.